# реализация get метода в Hashmap

Tags: java, android, java-hashmap

Есть такой Hashmap

```
public class PjColorImages {
    Map<String, PjColorImagesMain> properties_main=new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, PjColorImagesMain> getAny() {
        return properties_main;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String name, PjColorImagesMain value) {
        properties_main.put(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return properties_main.toString() ;
    }
```

Который работает в связке с этим классом

```
public class PjColorImagesMain {
    private String type,title,big,average,small,micro;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getBig() {
        return big;
    }

    public void setBig(String big) {
        this.big = big;
    }

    public String getAverage() {
        return average;
    }

    public void setAverage(String average) {
        this.average = average;
    }

    public String getSmall() {
        return small;
    }

    public void setSmall(String small) {
        this.small = small;
    }

    public String getMicro() {
        return micro;
    }

    public void setMicro(String micro) {
        this.micro = micro;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" +
                "type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", big='" + big + '\'' +
                ", average='" + average + '\'' +
                ", small='" + small + '\'' +
                ", micro='" + micro + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
```

И конечная часть где мне нужно достать из предыдущего класса getBig()

```
for(PjMainData pjMainData:pjMain.getData()) {
    String photo=pjMainData.getColor().getImages().getAny().\\getBig();\\???
    Log.d(TAG,photo);
}
```

Как правильно реализовать данный этап?

Comment: ни один из приведенных классов не является ни HashMap, ни даже Map. а в коде вы используете какой-то `PjMainData`. добавьте его в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashMap` это коллекция, в которой хранятся элементы. Их может быть ноль, один или несколько. Определитесь, какой именно элемент вам нужен, достаньте его из коллекции (например, по ключу `get("key")`) и уже у конкретного элемента вызывайте `getBig()`:

```
for (PjMainData pjMainData : pjMain.getData()) {
    String photo = pjMainData.getColor().getImages().getAny().get("someKey").getBig();
    Log.d(TAG,photo);
}
```